# How can I give more power to usb devices connected to my laptop?

Tags: usb, audio, power, usb-storage

I am getting a USB audio interface with mic preamplifier and I am worried if my laptop will be enough to power it (or if it won't get damaged by by the device).Is there a thing I could connect between them?

Comment: No;  Without zero information on the device itself, an educated guess is that, both data and power is done through the same USB connection. If that is the case your concern isn't warranted.

Comment: To really answer this more info is needed about both the device and your laptop, but yes you can buy powered usb hubs which you can put between the device and laptop.

Comment: USB devices have to comply with the spec, which defines the power available through the connector.  If you have every USB port used for devices pulling the maximum allowable power, you might see you battery run time decrease a little, but nothing will be harmed by using the available connections for their intended purpose.  BTW, a preamplifier uses very little power.

Answer (score 0):

PortPilot is self described as an inline USB power analyzer.

You should be able to use this inline with your preamp to detect if there are any problems with the power while in use.

I found it [here: indiegogo link](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/portpilot-inline-usb-power-analyzer#/story) while doing a search for "inline USB power."  The indiegogo site lists a site to order from, but as @Ramhound points out, it looks like they have an **official** site [HERE.](http://portpilot.net/shop/)